# Should stream's next_in, the compressed buffer be available for inflatePrime() ? - zlib

Tags: gzip, zlib, huffman-code, deflate, lossless-compression

I noticed on 2nd boot up, when inflatePrime() is called, `stream.next_in` doesn't have a compressed data buffer assigned yet, so how would it insert bits? (byte offset and bit offset, how they work to restart the inflation, is still bit unclear to me, here is my latest flow of things).
Thanks, appreciate any feedback.

////////// on 2nd boot:

// go to saved byte offset in compressed file

```
ZSEEK64(z_filefunc, filestream, streamCurrentPos, ZLIB_FILEFUNC_SEEK_SET);
    
    if (streamBits) 
    {
      int aByte=0;
    
      unz64local_getByte(z_filefunc, filestream, &aByte)); 
    
      inflatePrime (&stream, streamBits, aByte >> (8 - streamBits) );
    }

inflateSetDictionary (&stream, dictionary_buf, dictLength);
```

// 'someSize' is BUF_SIZE or remaining rest_read_compressed

```
ZREAD64(z_filefunc, filestream, read_buffer, someSize); 

stream.next_in  = read_buffer;
stream.avail_in = someSize;
```

// on first call to inflate, gets data-error with "invalid code lengths set";

```
inflate(&stream, Z_BLOCK);
```

////////// on 1st boot: where 'state of uncompression' is saved

```
if ( (stream.data_type & 0x0080) && some_16MB_wrote_to_output) ) 
{

    inflateGetDictionary(&stream, dictionary_buf, &dictLength);

    streamBits = stream.data_type & (~0x1C0); 
   
    // current file pointer could be way ahead
    streamCurrentPos = ZTELL64(z_filefunc, filestream) - stream.avail_in; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`inflatePrime()` inserts bits into an internal buffer. It has nothing to do with `next_in` or `avail_in`, which can be changed before every call of `inflate()`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses Mark.  Assuming the restarting steps are correct on 2nd boot upto inflate() call. I sould try setting the dictionary first, before inflatePrime. Anything else you can suggest? thanks.

Comment: The order of `inflatePrime()` and `inflateSetDictionary()` don't matter. Either can go first.

Comment: Some good news. After the _getByte() call, I need the file pointer to move backwards by 1 or simply re-seek  (streamCurrentPos). With that, inflate() didn't complain about data-errors in the read_buffer, it uncompressed about 31kb in the first call, and 53kb in the second call, after that its stuck at data_type 0x40, and before 0xc2 and 0x41. Anyways, a big progress. Thanks Mark.

Comment: On resumption, after inflatePrime call, my state->hold is 1, and  state-bits is 1. And that seems to cause inflate() to set the 'state->last' flag. And for rest, it thinks it is at end of stream.  When stepping thru the debugger, after prime call, I modified the state->hold to 0, well inflate proceeded, till the actual end of stream.  I verified the next_in[0] to [3] to be exact before and after resumption to increase confidence my restart byte offset on compressed file is correct. Thanks, almost there.

Comment: hi Mark, I got zlibVersion : 1.2.11, would this be a limitation for me, in terms of what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: No.............